# FIND item that CONTAINS specific text

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contains

I have following class

```
public class Response
{
   public Prompts Prompts { get; set; }
}
public class Prompts
{
    public List<Prompt> prompt { get; set; }
}
public class Prompt
{        
    public object message { get; set; }
    public object details { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve message of that `prompt` whose `message` contains 'Hello'. but its giving me error:

> Cannot implicitly convert from Prompt to string

So far I tried this lambda expression:

```
string message = Response.Prompts.prompt.Find(p => p.message.ToString().Contains("Hello"));
```

Comment: "its giving me wrong results " don't you think it would be helpful to us if you told us what those results were that it's giving you?

Comment: @rory.ap question edited

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: An *error* isn't "wrong results". It says that you are trying to store the result in a variable of the wrong type. Either store the result to a `Prompt` variable, or use `.message` to get the text.

Comment: You've defined a predicate that searches a string (message) for a value, the result of that predicate will return a `Prompt`, however you've said that the variable message is `string`. Should be `Prompt message =...`

Comment: you should really be carefull with your naming of variables. It looks very confusing when you use the same Name for type and variable_name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this line should return an object of type `Prompt`

```
Prompt pr = Response.Prompts.prompt.Find(p => p.message.ToString().Contains("Hello"));
```

if you need only the message you need to access the property. Since it is of type `object` you need to call either the `ToString()` method

```
string message  = pr.message.ToString();
```

or cast it to a `string`

```
string message  = (string)pr.message;
```

if you need it case insensitive:

```
Prompt pr = Response.Prompts.prompt.Find(
       p => p.message.ToString().ToLower().Contains("Hello".ToLower()));
```

since [`Find(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) will return `null` when no match is found, it is advisable to check for it when accessing properties:

```
string message  = pr != null pr.message.ToString() : "";
```

Comment: More linqy would be a select at the end.

Comment: @stuartd you are right, I got confused by the naming procedure